# Extract string from string containing with date/time

Tags: c, scanf

Given the string

`[FROM] Jan  5 2013 10:16:41 widget <__FILE__> <__LINE__>`

I want to extract the "peripheral", in this case "widget".

The "peripheral" name always starts in the same column - but it can have different lengths, so I suppose I could use memcpy() or strncpy() and use strchr() to get the position of the space. I will accept a code answer that does that and works.

However, it got a bit tricky as it has been a while since I've coded in C, so I've tried:

```
     char traceDirection[11];
     char month[4];
     char day[3];
     char year[5];
     char hour[3];
     char min[3];
     char sec[3];
     sscanf(line,"%s %s %s %s:%s:%s %s %s",  
                  traceDirection, month, day, year, hour, min, sec, peripheralName);
```

Everything is fine until hour, min, sec, and I suspect it might be because of the colons in the HH:MM:SS

Can someone give me some code, whether using `sscanf()` or otherwise, to get the name of the peripheral from such a string (I don't care about any of the rest), given that

- the lines always have the same format
- the name of the peripheral always starts in the same column
- however, it does not have a fixed length; it is terminated by a space

Thanks in advance. This is what happens when you jump between languages :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `int` to read Integers, NOT  `char`.**

```
 int day, year, hour, min, sec;
 sscanf(line,"%s %s %d %d %d:%d:%d %s",  
         traceDirection, month, &day, &year, &hour, &min, &sec, peripheralName);
```

See [Ideone](http://ideone.com/MXIyp0)

To read **only prefipheralName** use this,

```
sscanf(line,"%*[^:]%*s %s", peripheralName);
```

Here `%*[^:]` matches anything before first `:`. Then `%*s` matches anything before first space. But none of this scan assign any variable. At last `%s` just scans normally and assigns it to `peripheralName`.

Answer (score 2):

Your format string should be as follows:

```
"%s %s %s %s %2s:%2s:%2s %s"
```

You need four `%s` before the colon-separated block `%2s:%2s:%2s` for `HH:MM:SS`, and your code had only three `%s` in there. Also, the strings for `HH`, `MM`, and `SS` should be limited to `2` characters; otherwise, the entire `10:16:41` gets read into the `hour` string.

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/TsBDy8).

Answer (score 1):

In the above example, the `%s` format specifier eats all non-whitespace characters, so the hour is getting all the HH:MM:SS stuff (overrunning the buffer). To limit those to 2 characters, you can do `%2s`.

PCRE may be more helpful, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is truly guaranteed to have that format, the sscanf approach is overkill given your requirements. You already have the line in `line`, so you can just do

```
#define WIDGET_COLUMN 27
...
int widgetStart = line + WIDGET_COLUMN;
int widgetLength = strcspn(line[widgetStart], " ");
char* widget = malloc(widgetLength+1);
if (!widget) { /* handle OOM error */ }
memcpy(widget, widgetStart, widgetLength);
widget[widgetLength] = '\0';
```